# VSCode can't find my basic class in a separate file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am following a tutorial online of C# programming, but the VSCode is not able to find my class definition in a separate file.  I double-checked the class file is under the same namespace.

Here is my `program.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GradeBook
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var book = new Book();
             
            var grades = new List<double>() {12.7, 10.3, 6.11, 4.1};
            grades.Add(56.1);

            var result = 0.0;

            foreach(var number in grades) 
            {
                result += number;
            }
            result /= grades.Count;
            Console.WriteLine($"Average Result is {result:N1}");
        }
    }
}
```

And I defined a class named `Book`, which is stored in a file called `Book.cs`.  Here is the code in `Book.cs`:

```
namespace GradeBook
{
   class Book 
    {
        
    }
}
```

VSCode runs into an issue as follows:

> The type or namespace name 'Book' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [GradeBook]

I have checked that the class Book is using the same namespace; both `program.cs` file and `Book.cs` file is are in the same folder. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I have checked that the class Book is using the same namespace; both program.cs file and Book.cs file is are in the same folder. How can I fix this issue

By making `Book` public - by default it is internal and thus inaccessible.

```
namespace GradeBook
{
   public class Book 
   {
        
   }
}
```

Learn more about access modifiers here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers

Comment: I don't use VSCode and I don't know if there's something special about it but in general, the default access modifier for classes is `internal` and the code should compile just fine without the `public` keyword. If this is something that is specific to VSCode, you should probably mention that in the answer.